# Aerial view of different "floors" of building model

Tags: 3d-view, camera, visibility

I have constructed a 3D model of a multi-stored building in Blender, and have managed to obtain a floor plan, i.e. an aerial view, of the first floor of the building (see attached image) by:

Changing the view to be from above using <kbd>7</kbd> on the numeric pad;
changing the projection to be orthographic, rather than perspective using <kbd>5</kbd> on the numeric pad; and
enabling Backface Culling on the Multitexture toolbar.

Does anyone know how I might obtain a floor plan of the ground floor. I.e. How to remove all the first floor objects from the view? I have thousands of surfaces to be rendered, so simply selecting and deleting them all isn't possible.

Thanks
[image: First Floor of Model]

Comment: Did you try setting the near start and end clipping planes? You can find that data in the camera properties editor.

Comment: I don't think clipping works for rendering, so unless it is all one single giant object you can assign a Boolean modifier to, you are probably better off assigning objects to a different layer or group, so you can easily toggle visibility. Selecting from a side view should be really simple.

Comment: I don't need to render the image, so the clipping plane approach looked promising, but unfortunately it only worked in perspective viewing mode, not the orthographic one.
Can you tell me how I can assign all the objects above a certain height to a "layer" or "group", so I can toggle visibility?

Comment: You said it should be easy to select all the objects above a certain height from a side view, but I don't know how to do that. Can you help?

Comment: If you don't have time to answer, don't worry, and thanks very much for the help you've offered so far!

Comment: Problem now solved. (Pressing the 'B' key allows me to draw a rectangle to select them.) Thanks again.